# Apache Flink using Java - Performance Issue

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

We have a flink application written on Java and running on AWS Kinesis Data Analytics. The application reads the input stream from AWS Managed Service Kafka (kafka topic 1), then apply business logic (some calculations) and finally writes the output to another Kafka topic (kafka topic 2).

The parallelism is 10 and the topic has 15 partitions.
The expectation is to process ~20K concurrent data in 5 mins. But after all the optimizations we could bring it to a speed of ~20K concurrent data in 25 mins.

Could you please let me know if there is any other performance optimization that can be implemented to achieve the target.

Is Flink Async I/O going to be an option to further optimize?.

### Sample code:-

```java
StreamExecutionEnvironment streamenv =
    StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

DataStream<ObjectNode> initialStreamData = streamenv
    .addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(
        TOPIC_NAME, 
        new ObjectNodeJsonDeSerializerSchema(),
        kafkaConnectProperties);

initialStreamData.print();

DataStream<POJO> rawDataProcess = initialStreamData
    .rebalance()
    .flatMap(new ReProcessingDataProvider())
    .keyBy(value -> value.getPersonId());

rawDataProcess.print();

DataStream<POJO> cgmStream = rawDataProcess
    .keyBy(new ReProcessorKeySelector())
    .rebalance()
    .flatMap(new SgStreamTask());

cgmStream.print();

DataStream<POJO> artfctOverlapStream = null;
artfctOverlapStream = cgmStreamData
    .keyBy(new CGMKeySelector())
    .countWindow(2, 1)
    .apply(new ArtifactOverlapProvider()); //the same person_id key

cgmStreamData.print();

DataStream<POJO> streamWithSgRoc = null;

streamWithSgRoc = artfctOverlapStream
    .keyBy(new CGMKeySelector())
    .countWindow(7, 1)
    .apply(new SgRocProvider()); // the same person_id key 

streamWithSgRoc.print();

DataStream<POJO> cgmExcursionStream = null;

cgmExcursionStream = streamWithSgRoc
    .keyBy(new CGMKeySelector())
    .countWindow(Common.THREE, Common.ONE)
    .apply(new CGMExcursionProviderStream()); //the same person_id key

cgmExcursionStream.print();

cgmExcursionStream
    .addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer<CGMDataCollector>(
        topicsProperties.getProperty(Common.CGM_EVENT_TOPIC),
        new CGMDataCollectorSchema(),
        kafkaConnectProperties));
```

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Flink configuration options, but does "parallelism is 10" imply that you have 10 threads on one application instance, that there are 10 separate running instances, or somewhere in between?

Comment: I believe instance will be only one but there will be 10 task slots assigned to the Flink job

Comment: A "task slot" is something in the scheduler? If so, that sounds like separate instances. In any case, since you are only going between two Kafka topics, have you compared the runtime to Kafka Streams? Maybe the limitation is not Flink

Comment: Yes I have checked the runtime of Kafka streams, we have other kafka stream applications which are non-flink applications and they have better throughput than the flink application

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in what you've shared that would explain the poor throughput. But since you've asked about async i/o, I wonder if the flatmap is doing some external i/o. If so, that would explain it. If that is the case, then using async i/o should help substantially, provided the external service can handle the increased load.

I'm also wondering why the parallelism is 10, and what resources are available for those 10 slots. Are there enough cores to keep everything moving? With 15 partitions, you have 5 slots handling two partitions each, and the other 5 are handling one partition each. 5, 8, and 15 are more obvious choices for the parallelism. (Of course, if each slot is also hitting an external service in the flatmap, that also needs to be taken into account.)

UPDATED after seeing the code:

There are a couple of easy things you can do to speed this up.

One thing to do is to give the cluster more resources. You can leave the parallelism as it is, but give each slot more cores to work with, by putting the task managers on machines with more cores.

But before doing that take a look at optimizing the pipeline. Both rebalance and keyBy are rather expensive, and you are using them more than is necessary. Having a keyBy followed immediately by a rebalance doesn't make sense, nor does having two keyBy's one immediately after another.

Rebalance does a round-trip re-partitioning of the stream. It is typically done when changing parallelism, or when needed to overcome data skew. Rebalance is almost never used, except implicitly as needed when changing parallelism.

KeyBy does a key-based repartitioning. If one keyBy follows another, the second one undoes whatever the first one did.

Both keyBy and rebalance require serializing and deserializing every event, and sending them through the network stack. This is something you only want to do if it's strictly necessary.

Fixing these rebalance/keyBy issues will reduce the workload on your cluster. If that isn't enough to achieve the desired throughput, giving each slot more cores (so that the various stages of your pipeline can run in parallel) should do the trick.

Comment: No, the flatmap does not make any external call, so I believe async i/o would not help here. we have some complex business logic (calculations) that is being performed in apply() method of RichFlatMapFunction(). I tried to have parallelism as 15 but for some reason AWS Kinesis analytics is throwing connection exception if I have parallelism as more than 10, have raised a problem ticket with them already. Can you suggest an obvious partition, parallelism and cores for a throughput of 20K in 5 mins where 1 message is of 30KB size. Currently the cores is assigned as 1

Comment: Is that 1 core per task manager, or one core for the whole cluster? How many task managers do you have?

Comment: yes 1 core per task manager. I have now changed the parallelism to 8, with 15 topic partitions. Tested again and the throughput has increased only by (3 mins) which is 20K in 22 mins (compared to earlier it was 25 mins). Parallelism - 8, Task Manager - 8, Task Slots - 8, CPU Cores - 1 for each Task, JVM Heap - 2.70 GB, Flink Memory - 1.88 GB. Thanks!

Comment: (1) Increasing the parallelism to 15 should roughly double the throughput / halve the time, so it makes sense to figure out why that isn't working. (2) Does the pipeline have a keyBy anywhere, or are all of the operations chained together into one task (in other words, what does the job graph look like)? (3) Enabling object reuse should help a little. (4) RichFlatMapFunction doesn't have an apply() method. (5) Suggest you use a profiler to see where the time is going.

Comment: Apologize for the delayed response. (1) I still didnt get a solution for the issue with Kinesis Analytics for 15 parallelism. (2) Yes, the pipeline has a keyBy and countWindow operator. I could see the stream is distributed across all 8 slots for all the operators. (3) I am afraid to enable object reuse as they are referenced between the methods. Here is my complete sample code, please let me know if I am making any mistake here.

Comment: StreamExecutionEnvironment streamenv = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
DataStream<ObjectNode> initialStreamData = streamenv.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(TOPIC_NAME, new ObjectNodeJsonDeSerializerSchema(), kafkaConnectProperties);
initialStreamData.print();

DataStream<POJO> rawDataProcess = initialStreamData.rebalance().flatMap(new ReProcessingDataProvider()).keyBy(value -> value.getPersonId());
rawDataProcess.print();

DataStream<POJO> cgmStream = rawDataProcess.keyBy(new ReProcessorKeySelector()).rebalance().flatMap(new SgStreamTask());
cgmStream.print();

Comment: DataStream<POJO> artfctOverlapStream = null;
artfctOverlapStream = cgmStreamData.keyBy(new CGMKeySelector()).countWindow(2, 1)
.apply(new ArtifactOverlapProvider()); //the same person_id key
cgmStreamData.print();

DataStream<POJO> streamWithSgRoc = null;
streamWithSgRoc = artfctOverlapStream.keyBy(new CGMKeySelector()).countWindow(7, 1)
.apply(new SgRocProvider()); // the same person_id key
streamWithSgRoc.print();

Comment: DataStream<POJO> cgmExcursionStream = null;
cgmExcursionStream = streamWithSgRoc.keyBy(new CGMKeySelector())
.countWindow(Common.THREE, Common.ONE).apply(new CGMExcursionProviderStream()); //the same person_id key
cgmExcursionStream.print();

cgmExcursionStream.addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer<CGMDataCollector>(
topicsProperties.getProperty(Common.CGM_EVENT_TOPIC), new CGMDataCollectorSchema(),
kafkaConnectProperties));

Comment: I've expanded my answer. You should be able to speed this up without much effort.

Comment: The second half of the job, with those count windows, could also be optimized, but not that easily. I'm thinking that the changes I've suggested will be enough to get you the performance improvement you're looking for.